# css rounded and background colour

Tags: css

can anyone help me achieve this looks?

I need that checkbox and form fields with round corners and background with that colour

thanks
[image]

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: You know each corner can be rounded or not **individually**...right?

Comment: checkout ICheckBoxHelper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was this helpfull

```css
.panel-default * {
  background: #25A9DF !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #fff!important;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1!important;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1!important;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #fff!important;
}
.login-form .form-control {
  padding: 0 12px;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 3.428571;
}
.login-form .form-control,
.login-form .input-group-addon {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.login-form .form-control {
  border-left: none;
}
.login-form .input-group-addon {
  border-right: none;
}
.btn {
  padding: 12px 12px!important;
  border: 1px solid #fff!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">

          <form class="form-inline login-form">

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Username or Email">
              </div>

              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Password">
              </div>
            </div>

          </form>
          <div class="form-group text-right">
            <a href="">Forgot Password?</a>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="btn btn-block btn-info">Login</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to use border-radius to curve the corners. If you're unsure use this tool (http://border-radius.com/) to help you achieve it.

I would go about this by making 2 input fields use border-radius to curve the top corners only for the first input and the bottom corners for the second. Then style the rest as appropriate.